# How can I make todonotes use all of the margin?

Tags: margins, todonotes

I am using the todonotes package to place notes in the margin.  However, the notes it adds use less than 1/3 of the margin, which makes it so only 4-5 characters can fit on a line!  It's difficult to read the resulting notes.  There is plenty of extra space between the marginal note and the body; how can I get todonotes to use that space?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
blah
\todo{this is just a minimal example.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is difficult to guess, unless you provide an MWE(http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I would guess, that your `\marginparsep` has a very large value. Please have a look at (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout).

Comment: I guess from these answers there's not a `\marginwidth`, like `\textwidth` that can be used as the todonotes's default width?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, minimal is particularly bad to try the use of `todonotes`. If you use e.g. `article` (or whatever you would like to use later) it is already much better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
blah
\todo{this is just a minimal example.}
\end{document}
```

I used the `showframe` package to make the page layout more obvious. You can have a look at [this wiki page about latex page layout](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout). Once you get the desired behavior, you can get rid of `showframe` again.

If it is still not enough margin, you can utilize the `geometry` package to give yourself ample place in the margin. You could add, e.g.,

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,
            paperheight=297mm,
            left=50pt,
            top=50pt,
            textwidth=345pt,
            marginparsep=25pt,
            marginparwidth=124pt,
            textheight=692pt,
            footskip=50pt]
           {geometry}
```

and the upper page would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I was using [12ph]{article}.  This helps a lot.